# Using DSolve on a vector-valued ODE

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the given system

$$\bf{r}'=F(r)$$

where $r=[x,y]$ and F[x,y]=(−$\beta$*x*y/n,$\beta$*x*y/n−k*y)

But I have some trouble on setting up the code:

```
  b=3.3925;
  k=2.95;
  n=157759;
  F[x,y]=-b*x*y/n, (b*x*y/n)-k*i];
  r=[x,y]
  DSolve[r'=F[r],x,y]
```

but I get the syntax "F[x,y] cannot be follow by..."

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It's very nice that you got good answers for this question. However, in the future you should not expect responses without showing a minimum diligence on checking what is the correct syntax for this programming language.

Comment: The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
b = 3.3925;
k = 2.95;
n = 157759;
F[x_, y_] = {-b*x*y/n, (b*x*y/n) - k*y};
DSolve[{x'[t], y'[t]} == F[x[t], y[t]] // Thread, {x, y}, t]
```

Comment: (+1) However, for good programming practices, I would put the definitions of $\{b,k,n\}$ in some limited scope context , like `With` and avoid the lingering definitions.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks your advice. Since I feel that wrap with `With` or `Block` or a`Module` make the program not so readability, that is why I seldom use them. This is the reason why I am not a programmer :)

Comment: @cvgmt I  am with you on that one!

Comment: @cvbmt Why is Mathematica sensitive to use of variables? If use your code with s=x and y=i, I get just an error. It seems I HAVE to use x and y as variables. Why?

Comment: @Vangsnes That should not happen, how do you code it?

Comment: Ijust used s instead of x and i instead of i. But I use CLoud, which has many deficiencies.